# How to get dynamically added UserControl and cast to the Interface implements

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, interface, user-controls, casting

I have this code:

```
Control ctrl = Page.LoadControl("~/UserControls/ReportControl.ascx");
IReport rpt = (IReport)ctrl;
rpt.LoadData();
Panel.Controls.Add(ctrl);
```

So far everything is working as expected.
Now I need on `Button` click postback event to get the loaded control and cast to the interface to use a method, and tried this:

```
if (Panel.Controls.Count > 0) {
   Control ctrl = Panel.Controls[0] as Control;
   IReport rpt = ctrl as IReport;
   string result = rpt.AMethodToInvoke();
}
```

This cast cannot happen and the control I get from the panel is a `LiteralContol`.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you got any other controls in your panel?

Maybe give your control an ID so

```
Control ctrl = Page.LoadControl("~/UserControls/ReportControl.ascx");
ctrl.ID = "UniqueID";
IReport rpt = (IReport)ctrl;
rpt.LoadData();
Panel.Controls.Add(ctrl);
```

And then user FindControl on the panel

```
Control ctrl = Panel.FindControl("UniqueID");
```

Also as you are adding the controls dynamically you need to make sure you are re-adding them on postback otherwise when you run the FindControl() it will return null.

Comment: Tried this one. Not working too. No I have no other controls, I always clear the Controls property and then add a control that implements the interface. So basically you always endup with Panel.Controls[0].

Comment: So what do you get returned if you use the above? My guess would be the control is not being recreated on postback.

Comment: Thanx, man, when I mislead these things, don't you get angry? :P

Comment: No worries - glad I could help :) I only know this through experience as I have done exactly the same thing before!